# While using an online compiler, how can we solve this ' the class name and file name should be same ' error?

Tags: java

Main.java:2: error: class primeno is public, should be declared in a file named primeno.java
public class primeno

** Here is  my code (I used an online compiler) **,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class primeno
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
```

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what to do. Either rename your file to `primeno.java` or rename your class to `Main`.

Comment: "class primeno is public, should be declared in a file named primeno.java" I don't think there's anything left to explain?

Comment: I get that the file name and the class name must be the same ,but the problem is, I'm executing this code on an online compiler. so how could I save before I executing?

Comment: And please pick a better title for your next questions. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The name of a public class should match the file name. In this case, your class `primeno` should be in a file called `primeno.java`. Inner classes can be called whatever you desire.